# Remove Same Element from Array in C#

Tags: c#

How can I remove the same element from Array in C#?

e.g. `array{0,2,2,8,4,6,1,0,4}`
and output will be `array{0,2,8,4,6,1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;
...
var output = array.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Without LINQ:

```
int[] array = new[] { 0, 2, 2, 8, 4, 6, 1, 0, 4 };

List<int> result = new List<int>();
foreach (int element in array)
{
    if (!result.Contains(element))
        result.Add(element);
}
int[] resultArray = result.ToArray();
```

Comment: if i can do same thing in Visual Studio 2.0 then in that there is no concept like LINQ so what can i do?

Comment: `Contains`, `Add`, and `ToArray` are LINQ extensions.

Comment: @Edgar: Are you sure? I switched Framework to 2.0, removed Linq from using list and it compiles and runs fine. Check System.Collections.Generic.List<T>. It contains `Contains`, `Add` and `ToArray` methods.

Comment: You are correct. I mixed them up with the `Enumerable` methods.

Comment: Note that the `List<T>.Contains` method is O(n), meaning that this will have awful performance if used on larger arrays. (On relatively small arrays it should be fine.)

Answer (score 6):

You can use LINQ and do `myArray.Distinct().ToArray()`.

Comment: if i can do same thing in Visual Studio 2.0 then in that there is no concept like LINQ so what can i do?

Comment: You mean .NET 2.0, right? Without LINQ you'd have to write your own method to sift through the variables in the array and add them to a new array if that one already doesn't have the variable. The method would then return the new unique array.

Comment: Please Provide me Common Solution which are used in any version of ASP.NET

Comment: yes in .NET 2.0 but how can it dont? can we put array in to for loop ya anything else?

Comment: @amitvyas100688: Look at my answer, I updated it for .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that should work correctly in .NET2 and C#2.

(Since the `HashSet<T>` class isn't available in .NET2 it uses a `Dictionary<K,V>` instead for effiicient O(1) key lookups, ignoring the value.)

```
int[] input = new int[] { 0, 2, 2, 8, 4, 6, 1, 0, 4 };

int[] output = DistinctItems(input);  // 0, 2, 8, 4, 6, 1

// ...

public static T[] DistinctItems<T>(T[] input)
{
    Dictionary<T, bool> dict = new Dictionary<T, bool>(input.Length);

    return Array.FindAll(input, delegate(T item)
                                    {
                                        if (dict.ContainsKey(item))
                                            return false;

                                        dict.Add(item, true);
                                        return true;
                                    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to allow multiple entries with the same value at all you should use a `HashSet<T>`. Like that you detect directly when you add an element if it exists already inside. But this depends on your needs...